# Get distance between two SVG paths javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, graphics

I have two SVG paths, a and b, that I want to find the distance between. Distance varies along each point, so in my case, I want to find the smallest distance between these two paths. Is there a way to do this using javascript?

```css
path {
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M0,0 Q30,30,0,60" stroke="black"></path>
  <path d="M70,0 Q30,30,70,60" stroke="black"></path>
  <path d="M15,30 L50,30" stroke="red"></path>
</svg>
```

In this example, I define the longest path to be the red line.

As an addition, is there any way to find the direction that this is pointing? For example, if the distance method is `path1.distance(path2)`, could i get the distance as represented by a vector from the point on path1, to the point on path2? If this is not in the scope of your answer, that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

- Iterate over path a calling [getPointAtLength](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength) on path a
- Within the above loop, iterate over path b calling getPointAtLength on path b
- Use pythagoras theorem to determine the distance between the points in the inner and outer loops. You have the vector because you have the pairs of points.
- Whatever is the smallest distance is your answer.
- If you increase the granularity of iteration your answer will be more accurate but take longer.
- Note that if your paths are parallel lines then there may be an infinite number of nearest points.

Comment: Easier if you want to draw that connecting line, less Trigonometry: Get ``x,y`` points on both paths, create a new SVG path with it, gets its length